# Window function or Recursive query in Redshift

Tags: sql, recursion, amazon-redshift, window-functions, recursive-query

I try to classify customer based on monthly sales. Logic for calculation:

**new customer** – it has sales and appears for first time or has sales and returned after being lost (after 4 month period, based on sales_date)

**active customer** - not new and not lost.

**lost customer** - no sales and period (based on sales_date) more than 4 months

[image: dataset]

This is the desired output I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

The below Window function in Redshift classify however it is not correct.

It classified lost when difference between month > 4  in one row, however it did not classify lost if it was previous lost and revenue 0 until  new status appear. How it can be updated?

```
with customer_status (
        select customer_id,customer_name,sales_date,sum(sales_amount) as sales_amount_calc,
        nvl(DATEDIFF(month, LAG(reporting_date) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER by sales_date ASC), sales_date),0) AS months_between_sales
     from customer
     GROUP BY customer_id,customer_name,sales_date
    )

select *,
case     
        WHEN months_between_sales = 0 THEN 'New'
        WHEN months_between_sales > 0 THEN 'Active'
        WHEN months_between_sales > 0  AND months_between_sales <= 4   and sales_amount_calc = 0   THEN 'Active'
        WHEN /* months_between_sales > 0 and */ months_between_sales > 4  and  sales_amount_calc = 0   THEN 'Lost'
        ELSE 'Unknown'
         END AS status

from customer_status
```

One way to solve to get cumulative sales amount partitioned on subset of potentially lost customers ( sales_amount = 0).

Cumulative amount for the customer partitioned

```
sum(months_between_sales) over (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER by sales_date ASC rows unbounded preceding) as cumulative_amount,
```

How can it be changed to get sub-partitioned, for example when sales amount= 0 , in order to get lost correctly?

Does someone have ideas to translate the above logic into an
recursive query in Redshift?

Thank you